# Cycling through same scene on storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I have a single storyboard scene that will be displayed over and over again as the user pages through data fetched from a database. When the user hits the next button, the scene segues to itself and displays the next record.

The code may not be pretty but the end result *looks* right, with the navigation controller handling the animation. But now that I've got it working, I'm sure it's not the right approach - I'm using a navigation controller to pop this same scene over and over, when there's no reason for the popped scene to be held in memory (data is retrieved each time it's pushed or popped).

Curious whether anyone else has done something similar and hoping for some advice on what the best approach may be.  I've thought about simulating the look of the scene being popped and pushed by animating a subview - is there a third, better option? Thanks.

---

UPDATE

---

Testing has proven that the navigation controller is handling its own memory management just fine.

The view I'm working with isn't that demanding memory-wise.  If anyone with a similar query has views that are, and are concerned about exceeding memory limit - this would be a good link to check out:
 [Memory Consumption of UINavigationController](http://www.sevensteps.com/html/topic_EF478311-58F1-4A45-8FBF-2DE70D3A265C_11B92BE4-E9EB-4228-BA1D-EE30B61DD04F_5.htm)